# Positioning wordpress articles as relative in masonry during resize so no overlapping occurs

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-masonry, overlapping

Im creating a masonry layout using desandro masonry and the wordpress theme canton and each post resizes and the other posts should respond to it resizing, however they overlapp. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

After I make sure that Masonry.js was connected to my documents header, this code was able to fix my issue which letting each block remain as absolute.

```
 var $container = $('#boxes');

        setTimeout(function(){ $container.masonry() }, 400);
```